# Is calling a "thread entry point" function, in C, as "normal" function, a bad code practice?

Tags: c, multithreading, function, pthreads

I recently faced a very particular situation in which I had to think about using the same function both in a "normal" function call and as a "thread entry point" function, using POSIX threads, in C.

Let me better explain the situation: I have a program which, depending on the user choices, should perform different tasks.

Two tasks are quite similar but they differ in the sense that, in one case, one set of operations should be performed in parallel to another one, and in the second case, instead, almost the same set of operations should be necessarily performed before the other one, eliminating the need to create a dedicated thread.

Since the "common" set of operations is very similar in the two cases, I actually wrote a code like the following:

```
if(task_type==0) {
    // Create two threads
    pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,&common_operations,(void *) &args);
    pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,&parallel_operations,(void *) &args);

    pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);
} else if(task_type==1) {
    common_operations(&args); // Thread entry point function called as "normal function"
    sequential_operations(&args); // Different with respect to "parallel_operations"
}
```

Defining the "common_operations" function as:

```
static void *common_operations (void *arg) {
    // Properly casting void *arg to the right struct, containing, among the other things, "task_type"      

    // Function body....

    if(arg->task_type==0) {
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I've never seen a thread entry point function used in this way and I was wondering whether this can be considered acceptable or if it is a bad code pratice to mix things in this way.

Moreover, are there better solutions for this specific case?

Comment: I don't see any problem. Threads are normal functions, and can be used as such.

Comment: What I don't like is the `void *arg`. It is required for the `pthread_create()` but not for the direct call, so why not write a `common_operation(args_type* args)` and forward to that from the thread function? `void *thread_operation(void * args) { return common_operations(args); }`

Comment: @rodrigo Moreover it can't work as written, as later it is doing `arg->task_type`

Comment: Thank you!
Sorry, I forgot to write that I was casting `(void *args)` the proper structure pointer, containing, among the other things, a variable for distinguishing whether the function was called "normally" or as a thread entry point. I just edited the original question.
The idea suggested by @rodrigo can actually be a solution to avoid calling directly a `void * (void *)` entry function (which could seem odd outside the pthread context): I could create a function, which is then called within the thread entry function, when needed, passing the proper arguments...

Comment: You can actually remove the `if (task_type==0)` part altogether. If you pass a function as the thread function to `pthread_create`, the function can simply return, it doesn't need to call `pthread_exit` explicitly. The library will automatically supply the function's return value as the argument to `pthread_exit`.

Comment: Re, "... so why not write a common_operation(args_type* args) and forward to that from the thread function?" Why not indeed?  It's your program.  Your choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly valid to call a "thread function" like any other function. There's nothing wrong as such as long as, you convert (cast) to the correct type, it should be fine.
Whether it's a *good practice* is subjective. This is a so uncommon that it'd be hard to find anyone calling it outright "a bad practice, you must avoid" :)

However, you can rewrite slightly so that the "normal" function vs. thread function distinction is clear. And make it a `void` function so that it doesn't return anything in the single-threaded call, which would otherwise look a tad odd. This would also avoid potential spaghetti code.

```
/* Use it in direct, single-threaded call */
static void common_operations(common_arg_type *arg) {
    // Function body....
}

/* Use it in pthread_create call */
static void *common_operations_thread(void *arg) {
    common_operations(args);
    return NULL; /* equivalent to pthread_exit(NULL); */
}
```

IMO, the considerations you should give are just same for any multi-threaded program: the function remains thread-safe and any function you call from the thread-function are also thread-safe and so on. Otherwise, there's not anything to be concerned about.